# Call parent classmethod without reimplementing classmethod in child

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance

I have a multiple classes that share a parent. Some classes have their own support for a variable, and others don't. If a child doesn't have the variable I'm looking for, I want it to use the parent as a fallback, but since I didn't reimplement the method in the child classes, a super call doesn't go back to the parent, it goes to the parent's parent.

```py
class Parent(object):

    var = "Parent"

    @classmethod
    def echo(cls):
        if cls.var is not None:
            print(f"Echoing {cls.var}")
        else:
            super().echo()

class ChildWithImplementation(Parent):

    var = "Child 1"

class ChildWithoutImplementation(Parent):
    var = None


p = Parent()
p.echo()  # This works, prints "Echoing Parent"
c1 = ChildWithImplementation()
c1.echo()  # This works, prints "Echoing Child 1"
c2 = ChildWithoutImplementation()
c2.echo()  # Raises AttributeError, instead of running Parent.echo, it goes to object.echo
# I want "Echoing Parent"
```

In this case, `ChildWithoutImplementation` doesn't reimplement echo, so with super().echo() I want to use Parent.echo() as my fallback, but instead it's pointing to object.echo, which doesn't exist. Is there a way of having the fallback go to Parent.echo?

Comment: Neither child implements `echo`; it's *always* inherited, and `Parent`, as the class that "introduces" the method into the hierarchy, should never call `super().echo()`.

Comment: `Parent.echo` itself needs to handle the case where `cls.var is None` is true; there's no one for it to delegate to.

Comment: @chepner I think what he's expecting is that `ChildWithoutImplementation.echo()` will use `super().echo()` to call `Parent.echo()`, which has `cls.var = "Parent"`

Comment: He needs either to use two different var names for parent and child or do not set `var=None` in child class so that Parent one is inherithed.

Comment: @Barmar OK, took me a moment to work through that, but I see what you're suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

This does it and is AFAIK ok. I mean, is fine to refer to the baseclass just by using the class, in the baseclass.

```
class Parent(object):
    var = "Parent"

    @classmethod
    def echo(cls):
        if cls.var is not None:
            print(f"Echoing {cls.var}")
        else:
            print(f"Echoing {__class__.var}")

class ChildWithImplementation(Parent):
  var = "Child 1"

class ChildWithoutImplementation(Parent):
  var = None

class AnotherGenerationChild(ChildWithoutImplementation):
  var = "Third Generation"
  

p = Parent()
p.echo()  # This works, prints "Echoing Parent"
c1 = ChildWithImplementation()
c1.echo()  # This works, prints "Echoing Child 1"
c2 = ChildWithoutImplementation()
c2.echo()  #prints "Echoing Parent"
c3 = AnotherGenerationChild()
c3.echo()  #prints "Echoing Third Generation"
```

Alternatively, this works too:

```
            print(f"Echoing {__class__.var}")
```

Is also in a replit, https://replit.com/@ToniAlatalo/classmethod-inheritance#main.py

Comment: I have so far implemented a similar solution using `Parent.echo()`. This works in my example but fails if we had another generation of children. The __class__ implementation has the same weakness because it's doing the same thing.

Comment: What do you mean? I tested with `class AnotherGenerationChild(ChildWithoutImplementation):` and nothing strange there. Updated answer & replit to include that. But maybe you meant somehow differently.

Comment: It would behave as expected for AnotherGenerationChild(ChildWithoutImplementation), but the problem would be with AnotherGenerationChild(ChildWithImplmentation). In that case, using ChildWithImplementation would be a better fallback than Base, but it would still fallback onto Base.

Comment: Not if you don't override the class attr: `AnotherGenerationChild2(ChildWithImplementation)` falls back to  `ChildWithImplmentation` in the c4 instance in the updated answer & replit, as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The more Pythonic way to do this would be to simply let the default MRO take care of it:

```
class Parent(object):    
    var = "Parent"

    @classmethod
    def echo(cls):
        print(f"Echoing {cls.var}")

class ChildWithImplementation(Parent):
    var = "Child 1"

class ChildWithoutImplementation(Parent):
    pass  # NOTE: no assignment to var
```

Since `'var' not in ChildWithoutImplementation.__dict__`, doing using `cls.var` will simply look `'var'` up in the `Parent` class, just like with `echo`.

Comment: Good point, but I think the OP wants to define things in the classes and not omit the def. Maybe this is a better way anyway and he could adopt this approach.